# Python send some files in one directory using tcp

Tags: python, sockets

I need some helps. This is my decision part of `client.py` code for sending files.

```
if file1.exists():
    f=open(file_name1,'rb')
    print >> sys.stderr,'Sending file datasensor1 to %s ....'%server_address
    l = f.read(1024)
    while (l):
        print >> sys.stderr,'Sending...'
        s.sendall(l)
        l=f.read(1024)
    f.close()
    print >> sys.stderr,'Done sending to server %s' %server_address
    s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
    print s.recv(1024)
    s.close()

elif file2.exists():
    print "File datasensor1 not found"
    f=open(file_name2,'rb')
    print >> sys.stderr,'Sending file datasensor2 to %s ....'%server_address
    l = f.read(1024)
    while (l):
        print >> sys.stderr,'Sending...'
        s.sendall(l)
        l=f.read(1024)
    f.close()
    print >> sys.stderr,'Done sending to server %s' %server_address
    s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
    print s.recv(1024)
    s.close()
elif file3.exists():
    print "File datasensor2 not found"
    f=open(file_name3,'rb')
    print >> sys.stderr,'Sending file datasensor3 to %s ....'%server_address
    l = f.read(1024)
    while (l):
        print >> sys.stderr,'Sending...'
        s.sendall(l)
        l=f.read(1024)
    f.close()
    print >> sys.stderr,'Done sending to server %s' %server_address
    s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
    print s.recv(1024)
    s.close()

else:
    print "All Files not found"
```

It's work when in directory there is at least one from three file in decision. But when in directory there are `three` files(`file1,file2,and file3`), it just send file1. How do I can send all three files if in directory there are three files?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use `elif`. `elif` condition is checked only if the `if` condition fails. In your case, the `if` condition succeeds, so only the code under `if` is executed.

Thus, you can use a flag (e.g. `allThreeFail`) like this:

```
allThreeFail = True
if file1.exists():
    f=open(file_name1,'rb')
    print >> sys.stderr,'Sending file datasensor1 to %s ....'%server_address
    l = f.read(1024)
    while (l):
        print >> sys.stderr,'Sending...'
        s.sendall(l)
        l=f.read(1024)
    f.close()
    print >> sys.stderr,'Done sending to server %s' %server_address
    #s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
    print s.recv(1024)
    #s.close()
    allThreeFail = False

if file2.exists():
    print "File datasensor1 not found"
    f=open(file_name2,'rb')
    print >> sys.stderr,'Sending file datasensor2 to %s ....'%server_address
    l = f.read(1024)
    while (l):
        print >> sys.stderr,'Sending...'
        s.sendall(l)
        l=f.read(1024)
    f.close()
    print >> sys.stderr,'Done sending to server %s' %server_address
    #s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
    print s.recv(1024)
    #s.close()
    allThreeFail = False

if file3.exists():
    print "File datasensor2 not found"
    f=open(file_name3,'rb')
    print >> sys.stderr,'Sending file datasensor3 to %s ....'%server_address
    l = f.read(1024)
    while (l):
        print >> sys.stderr,'Sending...'
        s.sendall(l)
        l=f.read(1024)
    f.close()
    print >> sys.stderr,'Done sending to server %s' %server_address
    s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
    print s.recv(1024)
    s.close()
    allThreeFail = False

if allThreeFail:
    print "All Files not found"
```

Comment: i get error File "clie2.py", line 44, in <module>
    s.sendall(l)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 174, in _dummy
    raise error(EBADF, 'Bad file descriptor')
socket.error: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

Comment: What is `s` here?
I think removing `s.close()` and `s.shutdown()` everywhere except in the third `if` block might help? Try it once. If successful, I will update here

Comment: s refers to socket . s = socket.socket()

Comment: if delete the s.close(), it wont close the socket